# Images dissappear when height/weidth switched from pixels to percentage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, geometry

So I have 3 circular images on my page. For some reason, when I change their height/width from px to %, the images just dissappear. They work perfectly at 200px height/width, and at 50px.. but I want them at 20%.

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
  body{width: 100%;}
/*Parallax*/

.parallax{
    background-image: url("bg.jpg");
    height: 540px; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    position:relative;
}
/*Parallax*/

#header{
 position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
 left: 20%;
  font-size: 4vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #357eca;
  width: 50%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  opacity: 0.9;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;



}

h5
{   
  color:white; 
  text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: 900;
 
  /*-webkit-margin-before:0.67em;
  -webkit-margin-after:0.67em;
  -webkit-margin-start:0px;
  -webkit-margin-end:0px;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-colour:rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
  -webkit-box-direction:normal;
  position: absolute;*/
}
h5:after, h5:before
{
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
/*--- Circular images --- */

.img-circular1,
.img-circular2,
.img-circular3 {
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.img-circular1 {
  background-image: url('/Images/learn.jpg');
}

.img-circular2 {
  background-image: url('/Images/watch.jpg');
}

.img-circular3 {
  background-image: url('/Images/practice.jpg');
}

#container1 {
  top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrap {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navigation"></div>

<div class="parallax"><h5 id="header"><b>Welcome to RyanTeaches</b></h5></div>

<!--<img src="bg.jpg" style="top:60px;height: 510px;min-width: 100%;">-->
<div id="content">
<h2 style="margin-top: 0px;">Activities</h2>
</div>

<div id="container1" style="padding-bottom: 400px;">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="img-circular1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="img-circular2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="img-circular3"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
<h2 style="margin-top: 0px;">Activities</h2>
</div>

<script src="nav.js"></script>
<script src="template.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Site to see: 
http://ryanteaches.com/newindex.html

Any ideas why they dissappear?

Cheers.

Comment: height in %, it's weird, I guess

Answer (score 0):

It's the height that's causing this problem. Setting the width this way will work just fine, and if you had actual `img` tags instead of inserting the images using css, you could use `height:auto`, and it would scale the image as you want.

However, when you say `height: 20%`, it will calculate the element's height as a percentage of its parent's height. Since you haven't defined the height of any of the elements' ancestors, it will be 0 (you can confirm using your browser's inspector).

So, you could define the height of the `container` div, but given that you want it to be relative to the width of the device, your best option is probably to use `img` tags and `height:auto` instead of `background-image`.

UPDATE: per your comment, here's an example using `img` tags. I think this is more or less what you're trying to achieve.

```css
  body{width: 100%;}
/*Parallax*/

.parallax{
    background-image: url("bg.jpg");
    height: 540px; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    position:relative;
}
/*Parallax*/

#header{
 position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
 left: 20%;
  font-size: 4vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #357eca;
  width: 50%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  opacity: 0.9;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;



}

h5
{   
  color:white; 
  text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: 900;
 
  /*-webkit-margin-before:0.67em;
  -webkit-margin-after:0.67em;
  -webkit-margin-start:0px;
  -webkit-margin-end:0px;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-colour:rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
  -webkit-box-direction:normal;
  position: absolute;*/
}
h5:after, h5:before
{
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
/*--- Circular images --- */

.img-circular1,
.img-circular2,
.img-circular3 {
  width:100%;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#container1 {
  top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrap {
  //flex-grow: 1;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation"></div>

<div class="parallax"><h5 id="header"><b>Welcome to RyanTeaches</b></h5></div>

<!--<img src="bg.jpg" style="top:60px;height: 510px;min-width: 100%;">-->
<div id="content">
<h2 style="margin-top: 0px;">Activities</h2>
</div>

<div id="container1" style="padding-bottom: 400px;">
  <div class="wrap">
    <img class="img-circular1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"/>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <img class="img-circular2" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"/>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <img class="img-circular3" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"/>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
<h2 style="margin-top: 0px;">Activities</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: How would I implement the circular images using img tags? Do you have an example code?

Comment: @RyanBrown How does this look?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the images go away, you DIV's CLASS="wrap" have no content IE( no Width and/or height) for the image to be displayed in .
In short: 25% of an empty DIV is nothing

Just so you can see... for example

```
.wrap {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
```